# ChicagoBoss rejects user as a model name

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

So following this tutorial:

https://github.com/evanmiller/ChicagoBoss/wiki/An-Evening-With-Chicago-Boss

Everything works like a charm except that I can not use "user" as a modelname. A minimum usecase:

```
 -module(customer, [Id, Name, PasswordHash]).
 -compile(export_all).
```

This will work fine.

```
 -module(user, [Id, Name, PasswordHash]).
 -compile(export_all).
```

this will stacktrace, and on `./rebar compile`, it throws:

```
 ERROR: pre_compile failed while processing /Users/abe/github/awesome-name: {'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,["code reload failed: user"]}},
     [{boss_load,load_all_modules,3,
                 [{file,"src/boss/boss_load.erl"},{line,30}]},
      {boss_load,load_all_modules_and_emit_app_file,2,
                 [{file,"src/boss/boss_load.erl"},{line,44}]},
      {boss_rebar,compile,4,
                  [{file,"/Users/abe/github/ChicagoBoss/priv/rebar/boss_rebar.erl"},
                   {line,85}]},
      {boss_plugin,pre_compile,2,
                   [{file,"priv/rebar/boss_plugin.erl"},{line,105}]},
      {rebar_core,run_modules,4,[]},
      {rebar_core,execute,5,[]},
      {rebar_core,process_dir1,6,[]},
      {rebar_core,process_commands,2,[]}]}}
```

this occurs with both `{db_adapter, mock}` and `{db_adapter, mongo}`.

Anybody know what's going on? Is the user keyword reserved somewhere? I can't find it in the documentation if it is...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Erlang has a flat module namespace.  There is a module named [**user**](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/user.html) in the kernel application.